# Search thorugh links and identify RSS source with Regex, PHP or Javascript

Tags: php, javascript, regex, rss

I'm building a news / blog aggregator that's focusing on the Syrian conflict, and I would like to be able to identify the source. It's a simple site, and the aggregator is an external javascript that pulls RSS from my Yahoo Pipes. My problem is that I cannot find a way to identify the source (i.e. CNN, BBC, etc)

So I figured if I scan the document and identify the href source, I would be able to do something.

Let's say that we have `<a href="http://foxnews.com/blahblahblah.php">`, I would like to do a `IF href == http://foxnews.com { logo(fox); }` -- or something like this.

I'm not sure if I'm even "thinking right", but I'd really like to get my way around this problem. Any suggestions? Or are there Author info that I'm missing out on in my RSS pipe?

http://pipes.yahoo.com/pipes/pipe.run?_id=e9fdf79f13be013e7c3a2e4a7d0f2900&_render=rss

Answer (score 1, accepted):

RSS feeds are just XML, so the first thing you would do is find an XML parser for the language that you are wanting to use.

PHP has [SimpleXML](https://www.php.net/manual/en/simplexml.examples.php) built in and it's fast and easy to use.

You'd use that to pull out all the links like this.

```
foreach ($xml->channel->item as $key => $item) {
    $link = $item->link
}
```

That's simple to understand, our root XML element is `<channel>` then inside that we have all of the news `<item>` tags. So we loop through those and pull out each child `<link>` element.

Then once I'd got that far, I realised it wouldn't take me much more to do the whole thing for you. I strip the links down to just the domain by replacing http:// with an empty string. And then exploding the string using / as the delimiter. Doing this splits the string into chunks that are pulled from between the slashes. Therefore, the first chunk is our domain.

```
<?php
$url = 'http://pipes.yahoo.com/pipes/pipe.run?_id=e9fdf79f13be013e7c3a2e4a7d0f2900&_render=rss';
$xml = simplexml_load_file($url);
foreach ($xml->channel->item as $key => $item) {
    $link = $item->link;
    $link = str_replace("http://", "", $link);
    $parts = explode('/', $link);
    $domain = $parts[0];
    print($domain . "<br/>");
}
?>
```

This code gives me an output of:

```
www.ft.com
www.dailystar.com.lb
www.ft.com
www.ft.com
www.ft.com
www.ft.com
www.dailystar.com.lb
www.bbc.co.uk
....
```

Then it's a case of PHP switch statements to get the desired outcome for each link. Like so:

```
switch($domain) {
  case "www.bbc.co.uk":
    // Do BBC stuff
    break;
  case "www.dailystar.com.lb":
    // Do daily star stuff
    break;
  default:
    // Do something for domains that aren't covered above
    break;
}
```

Good luck!

Comment: Nicely done. They might want to keep an array of potential domains that they could use instead of the switch. That way if a new source is added it's not omitted.

Comment: That's a good option. Or the default case can be used in the switch statement to have a fallback for domains that aren't covered. I'll add that to the answer now.